# How to create segment control like IBInspectable properties?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

[image]I want to create custom control like segment control But i'm not able to understand how to create this kind of `Segment` IBInspectable properties. i mean it's elements increasing according to `Segments`.  as i know there is no support of array in `@IBInspectable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create that type of `@IBInspectable` (yet), but...

You can define a String variable as an `@IBInspectable` var, and add multiple lines to it. Then have a `didSet` method split the string into an array which you use internally (for example)...

[image]

Something along these lines:

```
private var internalTextArray: [String]?

@IBInspectable var segments: String = "" {
    didSet {
        internalTextArray = segments.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        // do something with the split-up lines of text
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what i want(Storyboard does not support the feature i want now)  and Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, this helped me out. I needed to associate identifiers with the segments of a custom UISegmentedControl and a string like this, while not ideal, worked nicely.

Comment: @Rob Yes, you're right. I guess this is the only way to create what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`@IBInspectable` properties is backed by `user-defined runtime attribute` which is not support `Segment` data type yet. So I believe that Storyboard does not support the feature you want.

Comment: True! Storyboard does not support the feature i want.